# Data is not stored correctly in data.frame

Tags: r

Im writing a simple if statement that should scan a file, check whether the first value of a row starts with a 9 and then place the row in a dataframe

```
 turn_time <- function() {

 ikr <- read.csv2("IKR_Dataset_2009-2015_test.csv", header = T) 
 data_frame <- data.frame(integer(0), character(0))

for (i in 1:nrow(ikr)) {

 temp <- substr(ikr$TYD_RESULT_KEUR[i], 1, 1)
 vin <- ikr$EEG_VRTG_CAT_V[i]

if (temp ==  9) {
    add <- c(9, vin)        
    data_frame <- rbind(data_frame, add)

           }
   }
 data_frame
 }
```

I now get the following output:

This however does not match with what i get when I do:

```
 ikr$VRTG_ID_NR
```

This gives me:

```
 [1] VF1JA04N522215749 VF7Y4WH0000WH4798 JMZGY193241146337
 Levels: JMZGY193241146337 VF1JA04N522215749 VF7Y4WH0000WH4798
```

So its not storing the ikr$VRTG_ID_NR correctly in my data.frame. So I assume it has something to do with defining my data.frame:

```
 data_frame <- data.frame(integer(0), character(0))
```

Any thoughts on what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just running:

```
ikr <- read.csv2("IKR_Dataset_2009-2015_test.csv", header = T) 
result <- ikr[substr(ikr$TYD_RESULT_KEUR,1,1) == '9',c("TYD_RESULT_KEUR","EEG_VRTG_CAT_V")]
result$TYD_RESULT_KEUR <- "9" #or maybe just 9, if you want it to be numeric
```

Creating an empty data frame and then adding to it using `rbind` is basically always a bad idea. Also, `c()` creates a vector, which can only hold one type of data. When you do `c(9, vin)` you are probably doing some unwanted coercion.

Comment: thanks. Any idea how i create a vector which can hold both a number and word?

Comment: @MarcvanderPeet You can't. In R, "vector" will generally refer to "atomic vector", which by definition hold a single data type. For mixed types, you use a list. Data frames are in fact lists, with the added restriction that each element (column) has to be the same length.